# credential manager in Windows IoT

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10, credential-manager

like in desktop windows, does Microsoft provide credential manager for Windows Iot Core 10 .?
If so, how to access it to store password and use it through my UWP application.?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows IoT Core, there is no credential manager app used to manage the credentials. But we can use some APIs in namespace [Windows.Security.Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials) to store and manage your passcodes, passphrases, and other identification information in Windows IoT Core. Please refer to the examples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/PasswordVault).